# Print lines in both file when 2 different columns match

Tags: awk

I have 2 tab delim files

```
file 1 

B T 4 tab -
1 C 5 - cab
5 A 2 - ttt
D T 18 1111 -

file 2

K A 3 0.1 
T B 4 0.3 
P 1 5 0.5 
P 5 2 0.11
```

I need to merge the two based on `file 1 col1 and 3` and `file2 col2 and 3`, and print lines in both files. I'm expecting the following output:

```
B T 4 tab - T B 4 0.3 
1 C 5 - cab P 1 5 0.5 
5 A 2 - ttt P 5 2 0.11
```

I tried adapting from a similar question I had in the past:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$3] = $2"\t"$4"\t"$5; next} $2,$3 in a {print a[$1,$3],$0}' file1 file2
```

but no success, the output I get looks like this, which is similar to file2:

```
 K  A   3   0.1 
 T  B   4   0.3 
 P  1   5   0.5 
 P  5   2   0.11
```

Comment: You seems to be near the solution. What is exactly the problem? What do you obtain with your code? Are you sure that the delimiter is a tab and not a single space? Why writing `a[$1,$3] = $2"\t"$4"\t"$5` and not `a[$1,$3] = $0`? `print a[$1,$3],$0` should be `print a[$2,$3],$0` isn't it?

Comment: Yes print a[$2,$3],$0, thank you! Would you mind clarifying this part? I can't understand ...

Comment: Yes, as said shellter, you seem to not well understand the awk trick to execute the part of the code for file1 and for file2, i.e. : `NR==FNR{code for file1;next} {code for file2}`

Comment: (editted for spelling, doah!) you need `$2,$3` as your key, because you are "operating" on your 2nd file, where your key is `$2,$3`. But you stored your data in the array with key = `$1,$3` from your first file. The keys should match up that way, if you use the `$1,$3` from your 2nd file, the keys won't match Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small problems in your code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3]=$0; next} ($2,$3) in a {print a[$2,$3], $0}' file1 file2
#                  parentheses -^ ----^
#                                            $2,$3  ----^
```

Comment: Please, could you explain why parentheses are needed?

Comment: POSIX says it _shall_ be parenthesized: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html. The `gawk` manual mentions them here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html.